# String Convert in this Format: Fri, 03 Apr 2015 13:55:40 +0000

Tags: javascript, json

How can i convert my javascript string into a date with this format?

```
Fri, 03 Apr 2015 13:55:40 +0000
```

MY string is:

```
03.04.2015 15:55
```

Thx ;)

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
let n = Date.parse('02.12.1998 02:12')
let d = new Date(n)

console.log(d.toString())
```